# How to hide svelte components from dev tools "Sources"

Tags: node.js, express, svelte, sveltekit

I have a svelte application, I have separated the backend from the frontend by making two different directories the `backend` is the express application and the `frontend` is the svelte app. I fetch the data from the express server when it is needed. I need an admin dashboard where I can control things but the problem I am getting is that I don't want to display the static HTML and the svelte files that are supposed to be on the admin page.

Now if I go to the browsers dev tools I can see the components that are displayed on the admin page and the code inside those components. Of course, the user can't access the sensitive data that is stored on the express server, but still, I would like to keep the admin page completely hidden.

I can fix this by making a get route on the server side and running a middleware in between that checks that the user is admin and then just renders the HTML, but the admin page needs to have a lot of functionality so I need to use svelte.

Image from the browsers dev tools

[image: 1]

Comment: Is your frontend a [SvelteKit](https://kit.svelte.dev) app, or a raw Svelte app. SvelteKit provides a router, and other niceties that allows for the components to be split up and delivered separately to the client, avoiding components (like the admin page) from being needlessly sent to the user. If you're simply mounting all of your components inside a single Svelte component, you will find that your components are all delivered at once, even if they're not immediately needed. In summary, Svelte provides reactive components, whereas SvelteKit is an application framework.

Comment: Yes @TomAnderson I am using sveltekit and I am new to it. I have the admin page broken down to many components and I have a +page.server.js inside the admin folder in routes and In that file it fetches to my express server and authorizes the admin. the fetch function is inside a try block and if the response is not ok (!res.ok) it throws error and the catch block will redirect to the home page. If the user is not admin the redirection works fine but the +page.svelte still gets added to the "Sources" tab in the browsers dev tools?

Comment: Try move the `fetch` function into a `load` function in `+page.ts`. This should run before the components are loaded into the client.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer! I was using the `<a>` html tag to navigate to the admin page and the data was preloaded for some reason. In my launched app I don't need to navigate to the admin page using the `<a>` tag.

Comment: This should be in comment rather than as an answer